# CheckStyle - JavaDoc for overrided methods

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding, checkstyle

For overrided methods Eclipse generate javadoc like this:

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.ncube.qtpokertest.listeners.PlayerChangeListener#
 * nameChanged(com.ncube.qtpokertest.events.PlayerChangeEvent)
 */
```

it's not a javadoc comment, actually, but it works properly. Checkstyle mark this comment as warning. How can I tune checkstyle to disable this warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correct you should just use the `@Override` annotation and not write/generate any documentation at all. This should avoid the checkstyle warning but nevertheless generate a JavaDoc which points to the parent JavaDoc (Specified by:).

Answer (score 3):

For older Java-Versions (before 1.6):
The `@Override` Annotation works only for inherited methods of super classes.
So it is better to use

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
```

which works also for methods implementing interfaces.
Checkstyle recognizes this comment as JavaDoc and you have only one place where you describe your method.